# There is no Key attribute in EF CTP 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-ctp5

According to the blog post here [Data Annotations in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx) there should be an attribute for a column called "Key" which allows you to mark the primary key of an entity.  However I cannot locate this in .Net 3.5 or .Net 4.0.

What have I missed?  I've included the reference to EntityFramework.dll and I've checked all the attributes under `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` but I cannot locate it.
[image]

I have set my project to .Net 4.0 full (not client profile).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [KeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx) is .NET 4 only and it is located in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly so make sure you have referenced it.

Comment: @Spence did you reference the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly in your project?

Comment: Why would I do that for?  Can you update your answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Spence, did you look at the documentation link in my answer? It explicitly says that this attribute is defined in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly.

Answer (score 6):

Probably your project is not targeting Framework 4.0, so, when you add the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations reference, it will not correspond to the 4.0 version, that is the version that has the "Key" definition.

Try deleting your current DataAnnotation reference, then change the project's target framework (right click the project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework) to .Net 4.0, and then add the reference to DataAnnotations again. Worked for me ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO Paulo!
The question you're answering was answered 6 months ago successfully.  While your input is appreciated, I just wanted to point this out in case you missed it. (Being new to answering)

Comment: What he said!  But cheers for the answer ;)  +1 for the introduction.